# How to circular background color with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot. But can not do the `perfect` circular background.If anyone here pls do this and explain this to me. Here is my `html` code:

Here is my snippet:

```css
.customization_text img {
  background: #383838;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 customization_text text-center">
  <img src="images/icon_1.png" alt="icon_1">
  <h4>responsive &amp; multipurpose</h4>
  <p>Proin in magna a ipsum viverra scelerisq enec turp, Nunc vestibulum fringilla accumsan ornare quis.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try: `border-radius: 50%`

Answer (score 5):

Use this snippet.

```css
.customization_text img {
    background: #383838;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 customization_text text-center">
<img src="images/icon_1.png" alt="icon_1"> 
<h4>responsive &amp; multipurpose</h4>
<p>Proin in magna a ipsum viverra scelerisq enec turp, Nunc vestibulum fringilla accumsan ornare quis.</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a perfect circle, give the div a height and width; then make the border-radius to 50%.

```
.customization_text img {
  background: #383838;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```